# basic PIG issue - subtract a group from an other

Tags: apache-pig, comm

I would like to subtract a group from an other on PIG.
I would like to do exactly the same what "comm -23" command is doing on bash, but I can't find any documentation about that on the internet.

So for example:
GROUP A is:
1
2
3
4
5
6

GROUP B is:
3
4
5
6
7

And the output, that i need is: GROUP A - GROUP B:
1
2

Comment: So what is the data structure of 'GROUP' A and B?  Are they bags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WinnieNicklaus suggested, [DataFu](http://datafu.org) is a good resource.  I wrote the [SetDifference](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/sets/SetDifference.html) UDF for exactly this use case.  Assuming you are working with bags, this will work for your use case.

Example from the documentation:

```
define SetDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

-- input:
-- ({(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)},{(3),(4)})
input = LOAD 'input' AS (B1:bag{T:tuple(val:int)},B2:bag{T:tuple(val:int)});

input = FOREACH input {
  B1 = ORDER B1 BY val ASC;
  B2 = ORDER B2 BY val ASC;

  -- output:
  -- ({(1),(2),(5),(6)})
  GENERATE SetDifference(B1,B2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [datafu](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu) package. It includes a lot of useful UDFs, including set operations.